# Designar Cargos através de reação com Discord.Js

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando aplicar cargos para quem reagi com emote em 1 mensagem, e está tudo dando certo, até a parte do "if" de dentro(Quando eu tento separar os Emotes). Com isso ele não aplica a role e nem a mensagem que eu coloquei para teste, mas as mensagens de "Mensagem correta" e "Reagiu" estão funcionando normalmente, mostrando ele ta reconhecendo a mensagem e que houve uma reação.

```
require('dotenv').config();

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION']
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd',(reaction, user) => {
    console.log("reagiu")

    const { name } = reaction.emoji; 
    const member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

        if (reaction.message.id === "803699867544453150") {
            console.log("Mensagem Correta")
            if (name === ""){
                console.log("Emote Banana")
                console.log("banana")
                member.roles.add("803708086857891899")
            }
            if (name === "grapes"){
                console.log("Emote uvas")
                member.roles.add("803707738005045269")
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: qual o valor da variável `name` ?

Comment: Mano a logica desse name é para preparar para ser uma "reação" no discord, como se fosse uma variável vazia, e é preenchida quando alguém reage com um emote na mensagem. Não sei se ta certo meu raciocínio.

Answer (score -2):

Tenta Assim

```
app.on('messageReactionAdd', (react, user) => {         
        const member = react.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
        if (reaction.message.id === "803699867544453150") {
            if (react.emoji.name === ""){
                console.log("Emote Banana")
                console.log("banana")
                member.roles.add("803708086857891899")
            }
            if (react.emoji.name === ""){
                console.log("Emote uvas")
                member.roles.add("803707738005045269")
            }
        }
```